# Powershell: Walking an SNMP OID and dealing with the output?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, snmp

I'm using SharpSnmpLibWrapper https://github.com/al-ign/SharpSnmpLibWrapper to walk a few SNMP OID's and return an output for phones at one of my locations. I was saving the results in a hashtable but am having trouble dealing with the output.

I created a hash and threw a foreach loop together to run a walk on four OID's per device and output to it's respected table as seen below

```
foreach ($device in $list) 
{
$Hash.$device = @{}
$Hash.$device.Name = @{}
$Hash.$device.Models = @{}
$Hash.$device.RegStatus = @{}
$Hash.$device.SEP = @{}
$Agent = $device | New-SharpSnmpAgent -Community 'SuperSecret'
$Hash.$device.Name         = $Agent | Get-SharpSnmpWalk -OID '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.1.43.1.6'
$Hash.$device.Models       = $Agent | Get-SharpSnmpWalk -OID '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.11'
$Hash.$device.RegStatus    = $Agent | Get-SharpSnmpWalk -OID '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.1'
$Hash.$device.SEP          = $Agent | Get-SharpSnmpWalk -OID '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.2'
}
```

What I would like to do is match the last xx digits of "Id" in output to group each device together with its values in Data.

$Hash.$device.RegStatus returns the following

```
    Source     Id                                Data           
    ------     --                                ----           
    Device1    .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.1.10 SEPxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Device1    .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.1.11 SEPxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Device1    .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.1.12 SEPxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Device1    .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.1.14 SEPxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However if I try to display just the Id's I rec' the following

$Hash.$device.RegStatus.Id

```
    TypeCode
    --------
    ObjectIdentifier
    ObjectIdentifier
```

So I'm not sure how to handle this or if my method above is even a good start. Eventually the desired output would be to have four OID's together so I can work with the data.
Example:

```
    1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.1.43.1.6.10
    1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.11.10
    1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.1.10
    1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.439.1.2.6.1.2.10
```

Should all be the same phone (I assume). If I can actually read the "Id" values in the table I can sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's an `ObjectIdentifier`...err, object, which is why you are seeing that. You'll need to inspect that further in order to understand what additional members under that class you have to work with. You should be able to see that information with the `Get-Member` cmdlet:

```
$Hash.$device.RegStatus.Id | Get-Member
```

or use its alias, `gm` (my personal preference):

```
$Hash.$device.RegStatus.Id | gm
```

This will output all public members available on that object for you to work with.

Comment: None of the public members would return the values I saw in the table. Using (for example) [string]$Hash.$device.RegStatus.ID[0] returns the desired response. Now I just need to figure out if this method will work for matching last 2-3 digit of the OIDs to form the data. Thanks for the response.

Comment: That indicates it's an array of some sort, but I'm not sure why it's returning the object type of the array in this case. You might do well to check for the OID in any index returned by the `ID` property, instead of assuming it's in the first index. Out of curiosity, what is the full name of the `ObjectIdentifier` type? Piping the output to `Get-Member` will show you the fully-namespaced type.

Comment: $Hash.$device.RegStatus.ID TypeName: Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.ObjectIdentifier
Whereas 
$Hash.$device.RegStatus TypeName: Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Variable

and one level up
$Hash.$device TypeName: System.Collections.Hashtable